# Plotly Dash with an opportunity to delete and interpolate outliers

Tags: python, plotly, interpolation, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am building a dashboard for plotting graphs with an opportunity to exclude outliers by clicking on points on the graph and change the data with interpolated values.

The main idea of this dashboard is to make data preparation faster and easier for people who don’t use Python. Also this dash will be used for simple data visualisation (sort of power BI handmade). And after all iterations a new file with clear data will be written as .csv without outliers.

Working on this i ran into 2 problems:

1. How to connect imported by dashboard interface data with plot layout.
2. How to choose points on the graph or choose time period in datePickerRange, delete values and interpolate (***scipy.interpolate.interp1d***) missing(deleted) values or change them with moving mean (***pd.rolling_mean()***).
   Also I found out that pandas interpolations yields kind of same results, so it will be fine to use it.

There is code block for data parsing:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):

content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

try:
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('cp1251')), sep = ';' )
    elif 'tsv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a TSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), sep = '\t')   
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    elif 'xlsx' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a new excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return html.Div([
        'There was an error processing this file.'
    ])

return html.Div([
    html.H5(filename),
    html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        data = df.to_dict('rows'),
        columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]),

    html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

    # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
    html.Div('Raw Content'),
    html.Pre(contents[0:10] + '...', style = {
        'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
        'wordBreak': 'break-all'
    })
])
```

and callback function for input box:

```
@dashboard.callback(
Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
[Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
[State('upload-data', 'filename'),
State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])

def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):

if list_of_contents is not None:
    children = [parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]

    return children
```

This part of code literally was taken from official documentation.
It is fascinating that I can look on uploaded data, but I would like to use column names and date from these columns for plotting the same way I do it in Pandas.

To choose column name I created two dropdown components:

```
#Create dropdown for X-axis
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'xaxis-column',
            options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns],
            value = 'Xdate')],
        style = {'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

#Create dropdown for Y-axis
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'yaxis-column',
            options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns],
            value = 'Yval')],
        style = {'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
```

And the part of code for graph:

```
dcc.Graph(id = 'graph')

@dashboard.callback(
Output('graph', 'figure'),
[Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
 Input('yaxis-column', 'value'),
 Input('xaxis-type', 'value'),
 Input('yaxis-type', 'value'),
 Input('XYeardate--slider', 'value')])


def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name, 
             xaxis_type, yaxis_type, Year_value):

dff = df[df['XYeardate'] == Year_value]

return {
    'data': [go.Scatter(
        x = dff[dff['Xval'] == xaxis_column_name]['Xdate'],
        y = dff[dff['Xval'] == yaxis_column_name]['Yval'],
        text = dff[dff['Xval'] == yaxis_column_name]['ID'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = {
            'size': 10, #was 'size': 15
            'opacity': 0.5,
            'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}})],

    'layout': go.Layout(
        xaxis = {
            'title': xaxis_column_name,
            'type': 'linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear'},

        yaxis = {
            'title': yaxis_column_name,
            'type': 'linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear'},

        margin = {'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
        hovermode = 'closest')}
```

I can add other parts of code in comments if needed.

Any comments would be appreciated!